# Why required option is not working in text field?

Tags: html, forms, textfield, required-field

I added a required option in the form, but it seems not to be working except email type.

```
<input type="text" value="Your name" name="name" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your name') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="email" value="E-mail" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-mail') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="tel" value="Phone number" name="phone" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone number';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Phone number') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="text" value="Your address" name="address" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your address') {this.value = '';}" required>                 
<input type="text" value="Coupon code" name="coupon" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Coupon code';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Coupon code') {this.value = '';}" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have already given them `Value` attributes. Try using `placeholder` instead.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P9q6b/1/)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your name') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-mail') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" name="phone" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone number';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Phone number') {this.value = '';}" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your address" name="address" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your address') {this.value = '';}" required>                 
<input type="text" placeholder="Coupon code" name="coupon" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Coupon code';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Coupon code') {this.value = '';}" required>
```

Edit: This would still not work perfectly because you're setting the value in `onblur`. I've updated the fiddle, removing the onblur and onfocus events. That functionality is provided by default by the placeholder.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required>
<input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required>
<input type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" name="phone" required>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your address" name="address" required>                 
<input type="text" placeholder="Coupon code" name="coupon" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Becasue `onblur` you are setting the value of the inputs by your `javascript` code.

Email is working because what `onblur` is setting is not a valid email address.

Comment: `onblur` has noting to do with required. It's just you are setting a value of the input by the code you have attached with `onblur` event. And, when an input has a value, it's got what it's required :). By the way, you can use placeholder instead.